# Emit to all the clients from Server side controller

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am new to this socket.io world. I have integreated socket.io to my client and server successfully. I am also able to send message from Client to all connected device using emit method.

But my problem here is I want to send some message from my node JS controller method. 
After a successfully inserting the data to database, I want to broadcast it to all the connected user. But somehow it is throwing error:

Here are my files:

## app.js

```
var server = https.createServer(app.get("httpsOptions"), app);
var io = require('socket.io');
io = io.listen(server);
require('./sockets/base')(io);
```

## socket/base.js

```
module.exports = function (io) {   'use strict';   io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('user connected');

    socket.on('message', function (from, msg) {

      console.log('recieved message from', from, 'msg', JSON.stringify(msg));

      console.log('broadcasting message');
      console.log('payload is', msg);
      io.sockets.emit('broadcast', {
        payload: msg,
        source: from
      });
      console.log('broadcast complete');
    });   }); };
```

## databaseController.js

```
exports.insertIntoDatabase = function(req, res){
  // code to insert data into the database
  var output = req.query;
  // Now I am completely clue less, how can I broadcast "output"  to all the connected users.
}
```

I have used https://github.com/krimple/angular-socketio-chat to setup my base project.Appreciate for any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are emitting events is wrong. Probably the repo you are following is for socket.io version < 1.0

Use this

```
io.emit('broadcast', {
    payload: msg,
    source: from
  });
```

Instead of

```
io.sockets.emit('broadcast', {
    payload: msg,
    source: from
  });
```